# A program in C to compare last digit of UPC code with a calculated value and check if its valid or not?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

So i made this code in c on visual studio, basically it takes as an input the UPC code of a product ( 12 integers) The last integer is like the check digit, which is related to the previous 11 digits by a formula. So the code basically checks if the UPC code is valid or not, by using the formula to calculate the check digit in the program itself and then compare it to the inputted value of the last digit :
Problem is, in visual studio the command prompt only takes the input and hangs,, as in it doesnt give any input and if i press enter the cursor blinks and just moves to a new line...
Edit :
The input I gave it is :
031564532525
Written exactly like that with no spaces

```
int main() {
    // initialize the 11 digits of the UPC individually // 
    int d, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, j1, j2, j3, j4, j5, first_sum, second_sum, total ;
    int end_dig;
    // take input from user of UPC digits //
    printf("Enter the UPC code:\n");
    scanf_s("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", &d, &i1, &i2, &i3, &i4, &i5, &j1, &j2, &j3, &j4, &j5, &end_dig);
    
    // caclulate what the check digit SHOULD be according to the previous digits //
    int last_digit;
    first_sum = d + i2 + i4 + j1 + j3 + j5;
    second_sum = i1 + i3 + i5 + j2 + j4;
    total = (3 * first_sum) + second_sum;
    last_digit = 9 - ((total - 1) % 10);
    
    // compare calculated value of check digit with input value, to see wether its valid or not. //
    if (end_dig == last_digit) {
        printf("VALID\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("NOT VALID\n");
    }

    return 0;
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: How far have you come in your text-book? Haven't it say anything about *arrays* yet?

Comment: When you run your program, what is the actual input you give? Please [edit] your question and tell us. Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: When you input the UPC, are you separating the digits with spaces or are they all together so it looks like a single number?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  It is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>` to expose the prototypes for the functions: `printf()` and `scanf_s()`  and `#include <stdlib.h>` for the prototype for `system()`

Comment: OT: not all shells recognize the command `pause`  Much better to use: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar() != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}  getchar();`

Comment: strongly suggest:  reading the whole number via a single call to `fgets()` into an array of 14 or more characters.  Then use offsets into that array to extract the individual digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%d` format specifier reads not just a single number but a sequence of decimal digits.  So the number you enter is being consumed by the first instance of `%d`, resulting it the program waiting for more input to satisfy the remaining format specifiers.

You need to split the digits with spaces so you can read each individually:

```
0 3 1 5 6 4 5 3 2 5 2 5
```

If you don't want to do that, you need to instead read in a single string, then inspect each digit in the string.